# how to embed a swf video within a list of links?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

I have the following code, and I want to replace the image by a swf video or .AVI video .
I have the object video code to play a swf video, but I want my video to play played inside the box where the image is currently in.

```
    <div class="pic_list">
    <ul id="picListItem">


            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" imgurl="1.jpg">Image</a></li>

                        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the anchor for the image with an object. The object will play the SWF video. You don't need an anchor.

How to use the object:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp